# Impossible to type anything after " ' " symbol

Tags: ios, swift, character

I want to be able to write latin uppercase letters and some symbols in my textfield.
So this is piece of my code

```
let apostropheCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "'")
let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "-/")
         .union(.latinUppercaseLetters)
         .union(apostropheCharacterSet)
         .union(.whitespaces)
 textValidator = CharacterSetTextValidator(set: characterSet)
```

But when I type " ' " I can't type anything after it(both for simulator and real device). It happens only for this symbol(I already have checked with other symbols eg. ":", "^" etc.  )
The result I want to see:
 I can continue typing after " ' " symbol. and get for example "MC'DONALD"

Comment: Maybe you can check/uncheck smart punctuation in `settings`-`general`-`keyboard`-`smart punctuation`